# Vertically center content which has display set to table-cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I have the following markup which contains a div with the class name `one-fifth-flex`.

This has the following rules:

```
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
```

However, the content doesn't seem to be vertically aligned and moves to the top. Is it possible to center it in the middle like in the picture?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```css
.button-bottom-50.btn-mchoice {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.one-fifth-flex.column {
  width: 20%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:400px">
  <div class="row row-flex button-bottom-50 btn-mchoice">
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide one-fifth-flex column col-btn-mchoice">
          <div role="button" class="ico-btn">
            <span style="font-size:30px;">+</span>
          </div>
          <br>
          <h5 class="h5blue">Plus</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide one-fifth-flex column col-btn-mchoice">
          <div role="button" class="ico-btn">
            <span style="font-size:30px;">-</span>
          </div>
          <br>
          <h5 class="h5blue">Minus</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide one-fifth-flex column col-btn-mchoice">
          <div role="button" class="ico-btn">
            <span style="font-size:30px;">x</span>
          </div>
          <br>
          <h5 class="h5blue">Multiply</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add position:relative to. btn-mchoice and display:table to parent of column instead of display:flex.

There is the second option of not using display:table but use flex box system.  However, flex box system is not supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You've set your elements with class `one-fifth-flex` to `display: table-cell`.

However, the parent has `display: flex`.

Therefore, `display: table-cell` is being ignored.

This is because the children of a flex container have their `display` value controlled by the container. Put another way, you can't override the `display` value of a flex item ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)).

You can get rid of most of this, as it won't work or is unnecessary:

```
.one-fifth-flex.column {
    width: 20%;
    /* display: table-cell; */
    text-align: center;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    /* float: none;
    /* position: relative; */
}
```

Try this instead:

```
.one-fifth-flex {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2t43r2m6/

Answer (score 0):

Give `.swiper-wrapper` (parent div) `display:table`.

```css
.button-bottom-50.btn-mchoice {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: table;
}

.one-fifth-flex.column {
  width: 20%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:400px">
  <div class="row row-flex button-bottom-50 btn-mchoice">
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide one-fifth-flex column col-btn-mchoice">
          <div role="button" class="ico-btn">
            <span style="font-size:30px;">+</span>
          </div>
          <br>
          <h5 class="h5blue">Plus</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide one-fifth-flex column col-btn-mchoice">
          <div role="button" class="ico-btn">
            <span style="font-size:30px;">-</span>
          </div>
          <br>
          <h5 class="h5blue">Minus</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide one-fifth-flex column col-btn-mchoice">
          <div role="button" class="ico-btn">
            <span style="font-size:30px;">x</span>
          </div>
          <br>
          <h5 class="h5blue">Multiply</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```